# Transparent background of content in a dialog window

Tags: gui-construction, dialog-window

Why dialogs created with `CreateDialog` cannot correctly show content with transparent background? The following example generates a plot, with white background, though it should be gray, as that is the default color of the dialog window of Windows. If, however, I move a window in front of the dialog covering it halfway or totally, the background reverts to the default panel-gray (see figures below).

```
CreateDialog[DocumentNotebook[
   Plot[Sin@x, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
    Background -> None, ImagePadding -> 30, ImageSize -> 300]
   ]];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(Left: the new dialog as it appears. Middle: covering the dialog halfway with another window, then removing the covering window. Right: Covering the window fully, and then revealing.)

The following approach does not work either:

```
Background -> Directive[Red, Opacity[0]]
```

This behaviour is more emphasized if the content is dynamic:

```
CreateDialog[DocumentNotebook[Column@{
     Slider@Dynamic@n,
     Dynamic@Plot[Sin@x, {x, 0, n \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
       Background -> None, ImagePadding -> 30, ImageSize -> 300]
     }]];
```

While it appears first with white background, even mouse movements cause it to turn into the desired gray color.

My problem is that I have a gui, where a plot is created and updated in real time. I would like to have its background to be the color of the underlying panel, but it continuously switches between white and gray during updating. Any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: Specifying a background colour for `CreateDialog` seems to help on my system at least, e.g. `CreateDialog[..., Background -> LightGray]`.

Comment: @Heike Yes, you're right, but I would prefer the default color if possible (as it is OS-dependent). Basically anything helps, that is explicit, e.g. `Plot[..., Background -> Yellow]` is displayed correctly. Only `Plot[..., Background -> None]` has this problem.

Comment: @IstvánZachar I actually had the same issue you describe with the dynamic dialog window based on a notebook. I just gave up and gave a `Background->White` command...

Comment: Does this issue affect v.7?  I cannot figure out how you made [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pg6Uk.png) happen.

Comment: Does `Background->Opacity[0]` work?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, celtschk: please see updates (`Background -> Opacity[0]` gives an error).

Comment: @István Zachar I did some tests but I'm only able to reproduce the pictures you showed when I move a part of the dialog windows 'off' the screen OR the windows grays out when I move the mouse pointer over the dialog windows going through the slider. Is that the same for you? It's a weird problem..

Comment: @Lou: exactly the same.

Comment: Has this issue been fixed since you posted this question?  If so we should tag it as a bug.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround might be if your looking for one colour for the whole window including the plot is to call the background colour at another place?

```
CreateDialog[
 DocumentNotebook[
  Column@{Slider@Dynamic@n, 
    Dynamic@Plot[Sin@x, {x, 0, n \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
       ImagePadding -> 30, ImageSize -> 300]}, 
  Background -> LightGray]]
```

this gives:

[image]

Comment: While this is a good workaround, unfortunately I need the default background (i.e. the OS's original).

Answer (score 0):

How about using `CreateWindow`? It defaults to the same background color (white, in the case of MacOS X) for the slider and the `Plot`.

```
CreateWindow[
  DocumentNotebook[
    Column@{Slider@Dynamic@n, 
    Dynamic@Plot[Sin@x, {x, 0, n \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, 
    Axes -> False, Background -> None, ImagePadding -> 30, 
    ImageSize -> 300]}], Background -> None, 
    WindowMargins -> {{654, 654}, {380, 380}},
    WindowTitle -> "Test with CreateWindow"];
```

[image: CreateWindow]

---

I grabbed the WindowMargins from your code (g, below).  You might want to play with some of the other options obtained by `AbsoluteOptions`:

```
g= CreateDialog[DocumentNotebook[
   Plot[Sin@x, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
   Background -> None, ImagePadding -> 30, ImageSize -> 300] ]];

AbsoluteOptions[g, {BackFaceGlowColor, BackFaceColor, 
     BackFaceGlowColor, BackFaceOpacity, BackFaceSpecularColor, 
     BackFaceSpecularExponent, BackFaceTexture, GraphicsColor, 
     GraphicsFocusColor, GraphicsHighlightColor, LineColor, WindowMargins}]

(* out *)
{BackFaceColor -> GrayLevel[1], BackFaceGlowColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
 BackFaceGlowColor -> GrayLevel[0], BackFaceOpacity -> 1, 
 BackFaceSpecularColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
 BackFaceSpecularExponent -> 1.5, BackFaceTexture -> None, 
 GraphicsColor -> GrayLevel[0], 
 GraphicsFocusColor -> GrayLevel[0.499992], 
 GraphicsHighlightColor -> RGBColor[1., 0.560769, 0.26273], 
 LineColor -> GrayLevel[0],
 WindowMargins -> {{654, 654}, {380, 380}}}
```

Comment: Sadly, it gives a white background for the plot, while the background of the created notebook visible around the plot itself is the default gray. The options listed are not for the notebook, but mostly for 3D graphics objects, I guess.

Comment: The background of the created notebook (in the CreateWindow code) looks white to me, both in the picture and on my computer.  Did you by mistake use the CreateDialog code (which is your original code) or the CreateWindow code?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. The `CreateWindow` code indeed gives white background, but it does not produce dialog-looking windows. Now if I use `CreateDialog`/`CreateWindow` with `DialogeNotebook`/`DocumentNotebook`, the background is always white first. In your case, it stays white, while in the other 3 cases it will eventually turn to gray if mouse/other window hovers over.